# Omnet++ with Reinforcement Learning Tools [ML]

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, omnet++, openai-gym

I am currently failing into find an easy and modular framework to link openAI gym or tensorflow or keras with omnet++ in such a way I can produce communication between each tool and have online learning.

There are tools like omnetpy and veins-gym, however one is very strict and not trustworthy (and no certainty into bridge with openAI, for example) and the other is really poor documented in such a way one person can’t taper how it is supposed to be incorporated into a project.

Being omnet so big project, how is it possible that it is so disconnected to ML world like this?

On top of that, I still will need to use federated learning, so a custom scrappy solution would be even more difficult.

I found various articles that say “we have used omnet++ and keras or tensorflow”, etc, but none of them shared their code, so it is kinda misterious how they did it.

Alternatively, I could use NS3, but as far as I know, it is very steeped to learn it. Some ML tools are well documented, apparently, for NS3. But since I didn’t tried to implement something in NS3 with those tools, I can’t know for sure. Omnet++ was easy to learn for what I need, changing to NS3 still seems a burden with no clear guarantees.

I would like to ask help in both senses:

1. if u have links regarding good middleware between omnetpp and openai-gym or keras or such, and you have used them, please share with me.
2. if u have experience with NS3 and ML using ML middleware to link NS3 with openai-gym and keras and so on, please share with me.

I will only be able to finish my POC if I manage to use Reinforcement Learning tooling online a omnet++ simulation (i.e., agent is deciding on simulation runtime which actions to take).

My project is actually complex, but the POC may be simple. I am relying in these tools because I have no sufficient experience to build a complex system translating a domain to another. So a help will be nice.

Thank You.

Comment: Looking for exactly the same thing, the best would be to embed it into OpenAI Gym environment to make the implementation of RL part trivial.

The problem is that you need to embed your omnetpp stuff into openAI, not vice versa. There are tools for interprocess communication like zmq, but the problem is in delay that inevitably occurs during this communication and that corrupts your online learning. I don't know any other solution except allowing this delay and accepting the fact that you are doing your learning for some bigger period, e.g., 0.1 sec., than messages are sent in the simulation.

Comment: There is also another idea, though I'm very skeptical about it. There is a feature in inet called network emulation, here is [a showcase](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/emulation/videostreaming/doc/index.html). You may elaborate this stuff by virtualizing ethernet interfaces. This allows you to fully implement your inet-application in python. However the problem here is that your kpis are affected by a) delay form delivering packets to virtual interfaces, b) delay from processing them to use in omnetpp. I don't know a reliable way to substract them from the final rtt, throughput etc.